# Is there anyway to record internal audio?

Tags: android

I want to make an app that helps you loop a sequence of sounds by pressing some buttons. The easiest solution for this is to record the audio, but recording external audio isn't a good idea seeing as how I'll end up recording a lot of other noise.

So is there a way to record internal audio? If not, is there any other solution to the problem?

Comment: What do you mean "internal audio"? I think instead youre asking about creating an audio stream out of notes.

Comment: @cricket_007, What I mean is recording the audio that comes out of the device's speaker. When I say internal, I just mean the audio without the external noise, like people talking, traffic noise etc. Could you explain what you meant by "creating an audio stream"? I am new to android studio, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the concept of recording audio is limited to a microphone in Android, but you can try searching for how to create a MIDI file in Java